# Obtaining span of plotted points from seaborn swarmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate dummy data.
a = np.random.random(75)
b = np.random.random(75) - 0.6
c = np.random.random(75) + 0.75 

# Collate into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}) 
df.columns = [list(['WT', 'MUT', 'WTxMUT']), list(['Parent', 'Parent', 'Offspring'])]
df.columns.names = ['Genotype', 'Status']
df_melt = pd.melt(df)
```

and I plot it in seaborn using this code:

```
import seaborn as sb
sb.swarmplot(data = df_melt, x = "Status", y = "value", hue = "Genotype")
```

[image: Link to swarmplot output]

How do I get the x-span of each group? What is the range of the horizontal span of the swarmplot for the Parent group, for instance?

Comment: Check what `swarmplot` returns, you should be able to dig down and find the artists which will contain their data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the information from the `collections` which are created by `swarmplot`.

`swarmplot` actually returns the matplotlib `Axes` instance, and from there we can find the `PathCollections` that it creates. To get the positions, we can use `.get_offsets()`.

Here is your example, modified to find and print the swarm limits, and then use them to plot a box around the swarms.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# Generate dummy data.
a = np.random.random(75)
b = np.random.random(75) - 0.6
c = np.random.random(75) + 0.75 

# Collate into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}) 
df.columns = [list(['WT', 'MUT', 'WTxMUT']), list(['Parent', 'Parent', 'Offspring'])]
df.columns.names = ['Genotype', 'Status']
df_melt = pd.melt(df) 

ax = sb.swarmplot(data = df_melt, x = "Status", y = "value", hue = "Genotype")

def getdatalim(coll):
    x,y = np.array(coll.get_offsets()).T
    try:
        print 'xmin={}, xmax={}, ymin={}, ymax={}'.format(
                x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max())
        rect = Rectangle((x.min(),y.min()),x.ptp(),y.ptp(),edgecolor='k',facecolor='None',lw=3)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    except ValueError:
        pass

getdatalim(ax.collections[0]) # "Parent"
getdatalim(ax.collections[1]) # "Offspring"

plt.show()
```

which prints:

```
xmin=-0.107313729132, xmax=0.10661092707, ymin=-0.598534246847, ymax=0.980441247759
xmin=0.942829146473, xmax=1.06105941656, ymin=0.761277608688, ymax=1.74729717464
```

And here's the figure:

[image]

Comment: great answer! small nitpick -- might be good to include `ax` as an argument to `getdatalim`.

Comment: For this minimal example that's not really necessary, but of course you could include that if your use-case requires it