# How to Iterate over points in chart?

Tags: python, seaborn

I need to iterate over every points in the following seaborne chart to obtain the coordinates and the color for every point  to put this information in the dictionary .and use this dictionary later when the mouse hover over the point the annotation display the category of this point because I have a lot

```
SInteractions_Graph = sns.swarmplot(x="KPI", y="value", hue="Platform", data=irisS)
```

and the chart looks like this

which produce the following chart :

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07wls.jpg)

Comment: Seaborn swarmplot return the Ax object so you can use it..  see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615354/obtaining-span-of-plotted-points-from-seaborn-swarmplot

Comment: Yes I mange to obtain the coordinate but still I need the color

Comment: oky I also obtain  the color  but  as a array of numbers do you have idea how convert it to the hexadecimal to compare it with the dictionary of hue  ?